# Excel File Opens as an Offline Copy

Tags: 2010, excel, offline

For some reason, when I check out or open (Read Only) this one Excel file in a document library, it opens as an "offline copy".

The File menu in Excel says it's an `"Offline Copy: Workbook is in read-only mode".` It gives you an option to `"View offline files"` and `"Resolve"` them.

Why is it doing this, and how do you get rid of it?  There is no "Sync to Offline Workspace" available for this document library. It's been turned off.

Any ideas how this happened and what to do about it?

Comment: Is this a self contained Excel file or are there references to outside data sources? Perhaps it is the data sources that are "Offline".

Comment: Try saving the doc locally, rename it slightly and reupload it with the new name. See if this works. I find sometimes documents become content and eventually unhappy and stop playing well with others. Sometimes killing them, and allowing them to reincarnate snaps them back into reality.